# groovy read from URL file and store it in the list

Tags: groovy

I have file stored in the website, I want to read the file and store each line in array list.

Currently using this code, it works. Is there a better way of doing this part of the code.

```
def data = u.toURL().text
def keys = new ArrayList()
data.eachLine {
   keys.add(it)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simplify it a bit:

```
def keys = []
u.toURL().text.eachLine{ keys << it }
```

and for such simple kind of job, it's just fine

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
def keys = u.toURL().readLines()
```

?

As in the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html#readLines()).